# I get more than one output in python 3.x

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I really don't know what is causing this to happen so if you can please help :)
The program is supposed to find palindromes from given list ex. 121,23,2,3883 and give output 3883,2,121
but my output look more like this:

```
3883
3883,2
3883,2,121
```

I thick it is just some small thing I don't know about. Here is the code:

```
lista=[]
lista = [int(clan) for clan in input("Unesi članove niza : ").split(',')]
lista.reverse()
rezultat=[]
for i in lista:
if i < 0:
    i = i * -1
    t = i
    rev = 0
    rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
    t = t // 10
    i = i * -1
    rezultat.append(str(i))
else:
        t = i
        rev = 0
while t > 0:
    rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
    t = t // 10
    if rev == i:
        rezultat.append(str(i))
        print(','.join(rezultat))
```

Comment: Please don't go in a complex way think it simple :)

Comment: For your program, the answer is just to indent the last line to leftmost. That's it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are printing it in a loop, just make the following change:

```
lista=[]
lista = [int(clan) for clan in input("Unesi članove niza : ").split(',')]
lista.reverse()
rezultat=[]
for i in lista:
    if i < 0:
        i = i * -1
        t = i
        rev = 0
        rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
        t = t // 10
        i = i * -1
        rezultat.append(str(i))
    else:
            t = i
            rev = 0
    while t > 0:
        rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
        t = t // 10
        if rev == i:
            rezultat.append(str(i))
print(','.join(rezultat))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go one-liner :)

```
sample = [121, 23, 2, 3883]
print(sorted(filter(lambda x: str(x) == str(x)[::-1], sample),reverse=True))
```

Comment: Or with a list comprehension: `print(','.join(v for v in input_("Unesi članove niza : ").split(',') if v == v[::-1]))`

Comment: Yep! this is also fine :)

Answer (score 0):

try removing
`print(','.join(rezultat))`
from the while block

I think that should stop the repeated results